# How to Parse Json with NSJSONSerialization from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I am using `NSURLSession` and `NSURLSessionDataTask` to send a post request and then get the response and store it in a variable that is an NSString and then log it. My function right now looks like this:

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
     NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

     NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.org/mobile_app/studentregister.php"];
     NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     NSString * params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&displayname=%@&password=%@&passwordc=%@&email=%@&teachercode=%@", username, displayname, password, passwordc, email, teacherCode];
     [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
     [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
     if(error == nil)
     {
     NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"Json = %@",text);

     }

     }];
     [dataTask resume];
```

When I run the request it returns the following in the debugging terminal:

```
Json = {"userCharLimit":"Your username must be between 5 and 25 characters in length"}{"displaynameCharLim":"Your displayname must be between 5 and 25 characters in length"}{"passLimit":"Your password must be between 8 and 50 characters in length"}{"emailInvalid":"Not a valid email address"}{"teacherCodeLength":"Your teacher code is not 5 to 12 characters"}
```

How can I know parse this using `NSJSONSerialization`? Can this even be parsed or do I have some formatting to do on the php? This is my first web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSJSONSerialization uses NSData not NSString.

Replace your line...

```
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData...
```

With something like this...

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

The dictionary object will now be a representation of the JSON.

This depends on the JSON being correct though :-)

Also, this has been asked hundreds of times before.

Comment: I am getting Dictionary is null

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```